# Is it reasonable to use PhoneGap to create an app that will run on both mobile and regular web browser?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, cordova

I have just started looking into PhoneGap, but I have a requirement that I need to port an old .Net CE forms app to modern phones (android, ios, wp7/8)

But, another requirements is that we need to be able to use the same "screens" on our accompanying regular web application (MVC3 .Net web site).  The idea here would be on our existing pages, make an AJAX call to load up one of the PhoneGap-created screens

I have read about it being technically possible if you stick to the basic device functions, but I anticipate a lot of other problems, for example:

- Most documents that I have read suggestion developing PhoneGap apps as single-page applications.  But I assume that if I need to access the "pages" from a normal browser, this is not an option.  But I don't actually know if either way is possible at this point.
- On some of the pages, I will need plugin functionality like a barcode scanner.  But those same pages will still need to be available on a regular browser.  From the browser, the user would just be expected to type in the text instead of scanning.  I expect those to cause problems whether or not it is a single page application

There are probably a lot more issues, but I would just like to know if this is whole mobile/browser simultaneous development idea is bad or impossible.

Additionally, if it is possible, would that mean I can't use any js frameworks like jQuery Mobile, Angular.js, etc...?

Answer (score 0):

Well, for sure its possible!

Within your javascript-code you can check, wheter the current user is calling the page from the browser or from an native app. for example, you can show a textfield instead of opening the barcodescanner.

And why should this mean that you cannot use JS-framworks? they can be used for the frontend no matter if youre developing an app for the browser or for phonegap!

Comment: Thanks. One reason I thought using JS frameworks would be an issue is if I used a more mobile-centric framework like JQM or Sencha.  I have never used a mobile framework yet and so don't know if they do things in a particularity different way that break when in a desktop browser.

Comment: Agree with brauchle_andi - yes very doable. You do have to sometimes add browser-or-mobile code - specifically for hardware/device specific stuff but most of the time it's pretty easy to do. When you get into stuff like FileSystem access it gets a bit hairy - but for general client/server web-app functionality you can run most all of your code through either a device or a computer browser.